# SQL Convert Date from dd.mm.yyyy to dd-mm-yyyy

Tags: sql, date

I want to select data which is set in a specific date range. Unfortunately I get the date in this form:

```
01.05.2016 and 02.06.2016
```

In the database, the date are in the form:

```
2013-06-21
```

How can I convert the date in my sql query?

```
SELECT `artikel`.* 
FROM `artikel` 
WHERE (buchungsdatum >= '01.05.2016') AND (buchungsdatum <= '02.06.2016')
```

Comment: Tag the dbms used!

Comment: What rdbms are you using?

Comment: I use phpmyadmin 5.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is MySQL, you can use [**`STR_TO_DATE`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date):

```
SELECT `artikel`.* 
FROM `artikel` 
WHERE 
    buchungsdatum >= STR_TO_DATE('01.05.2016','%d.%m.%Y')
    AND buchungsdatum <= STR_TO_DATE('02.06.2016', '%d.%m.%Y')
```

Check [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) for the available date formats.

Answer (score 1):

Try DATE_FORMAT() function of mysql as DATE_FORMAT() function is used to display date/time data in different formats.:

```
SELECT `artikel`.* 
FROM `artikel` 
WHERE (DATE_FORMAT(buchungsdatum, "%d.%m.%Y") >= '01.05.2016') AND (DATE_FORMAT(buchungsdatum, "%d.%m.%Y") <= '02.06.2016')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
select 
SUBSTRING(convert(varchar(10),REPLACE('01.05.2016','.', ''),103),5,4)+ '-'+
SUBSTRING(convert(varchar(10),REPLACE('01.05.2016','.', ''),103),3,2)+'-'+
SUBSTRING(convert(varchar(10),REPLACE('01.05.2016','.', ''),103),1,2)
```

It formats 01.05.2016 to 2016-05-01

I have to mention that it changes the 01.05.2016 to 01052016 and then it formats it.